# Parse JSON android

Tags: java, android, json

```
[
  {
    "state":1,
    "phone":"123456789",
    "message":"Message number 1"
  },
  {
    "state":1,
    "phone":"123456789",
    "message":"Message number 1"
  }
]
```

How I can parse this??

I tried:

> JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result); // Result is json
>   response

but got: 
java: unreported exception org.json.JSONException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

Please help.

Comment: Have you looked up the error before posting? Also, after you do that and solve it, is your JSON an array or an object?

Comment: Thank @Sotirios Delimanolis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all 
you can try catch blok to detect what is the error using this:

```
try
{
//do parsing
 } catch (JSONException e) {
        //some exception handler code.
    }
```

you can parse it like this:

```
   JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
  for(int i=0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
    String state_= jObject.getString("state"));   
             //you can do to the others
                  ............
    }
```